# "<" character in kotlin language translator not working

Tags: android, xml, translation

I'm about to translate my app into different languages. My problem is though, that kotlins 'translation tool' doesn't allow special characters like "<". So if I have the english sentence

"He is <180cm tall"

and want to translate it into spanish, it would be:

"Tiene una altura de <180 cm".

This however doesn't work, because with `<string name="heigt">Tiene una altura de <180 cm</string>` kotlin is irritated with the "<" I think, because kotlin thinks the string ended or whatever.

The same with "\<" or with &#60 or U+003C.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about kotlin but XML.

Use `&lt;` to entity-escape a lower than character.